# Discovery Service Won't Start

Tags: web8, discovery-service

When installing the discovery service I receive the following issue while trying to start the service

```
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:9082 failed
ERROR: Unable to start service during timeframe of 60s
Please check logs and configuration files.
```

The service is installed correctly.

If I try to start it from the Services dialog, I get the following error

[image]

There is very little information in the Event Viewer, only one error

```
The SDL Web Discovery Service - Staging service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.
```

There are no log files created by the service itself.

I first suspected a firewall, but have been assured the firewall is turned off on the server.

Confirmed via Resource Monitor that no other service is running on 9082

Comment: You mean Port 9082? Try running the Discovery Service on the command-line first using the start.ps1 PowerShell script (specifying the same port).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd forgotten to install one of the prerequisites. It was my own fault.

Java was not installed on the Content Delivery Server.

Comment: Which prerequisites are you talking about as we are also facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: +1 to Sumit, am facing the same issue, would be interested to know what pre-req was missed.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and got the same initial PowerShell error message:

```
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:8082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:8082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:8082 failed
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:8082 failed
...
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:8082 failed
ERROR: Unable to start service during timeframe of 60s
Please check logs and configuration files.
```

And the Windows Services wouldn't start.

However, my problem was caused because I didn't deploy the `cd_licenses.xml` file to the target (`C:\SDL\Web`) folder **before** running the `quickinstall.ps1` PowerShell script.

Not the solution to your issue, Chris, but may help someone else that encounters this problem and finds your question here!

Answer (score 1):

I had issues because of following reasons.

- Port was not opened on the server
- Incorrect version of java
- Lately when i unzipped my services, i forgot to unblock it from properties.
- License was not there,  or incorrect no of cpu.

Answer (score -2):

I faced same issue and found that logback.xml file was missing some tags which was creating the problem. We used standard file and it started working.